# Problem with Activity switching -Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I'm trying to switch to a different activity from my app. The new activity has a webview layout. When I press the enter key, I can see the new activity hardly for a second and then I'm back with original app. Can someone please tell me more on this?

Comment: When you press the enter key? On the Android hard keyboard? "You're back with the original app"? What does that mean?

Comment: Does the logcat show any errors?  Some code from the second activity would be helpful.

Comment: I mean when I touch the "Done" key on keyboard, the new activity flashes just for a second.

Comment: @gjhatokach: "Can someone please tell me more on this?" -- you have not provided anywhere *near* enough information to go on. Please review other StackOverflow questions to learn the level of detail you need to provide in order to get assistance.

Answer (score -1):

I think your new activity might be destroyed by something like calling finish or something like this.

Comment: No, I have not made a call to finish(), I am using startActivity(myIntent) to call new activity